# Given $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3x+2}}$ obtain the Taylor Series about $x=1$ and find the convergence radius.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I need help with this Taylor Series. This is what I've done.

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3x+2}}$$

$$f(1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3(1)+2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{5}}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{-1}{3}(3x+2)^{\frac{-4}{3}}\cdot3=\frac{-1}{\sqrt[3]{(3x+2)^4}}$$

$$f'(1)=\frac{-1}{\sqrt[3]{(3(1)+2)^4}}=\frac{-1}{5\sqrt[3]{5}}$$

$$f''(x)=\frac{4}{3}(3x+2)^{\frac{-7}{3}}\cdot3=\frac{4}{\sqrt[3]{(3x+2)^7}}$$

$$f''(1)=\frac{4}{\sqrt[3]{(3(1)+2)^7}}=\frac{4}{5^2\sqrt[3]{5}}$$

$$f'''(x)=\frac{-28}{3}(3x+2)^{\frac{-10}{3}}\cdot3=\frac{-28}{\sqrt[3]{(3x+2)^{10}}}$$

$$f'''(1)=\frac{-28}{\sqrt[3]{(3(1)+2)^{10}}}=\frac{-28}{5^3\sqrt[3]{5}}$$

$$f^4(x)=\frac{280}{3}(3x+2)^{\frac{-13}{3}}\cdot3=\frac{280}{\sqrt[3]{(3x+2)^{13}}}$$

$$f^4(1)=\frac{280}{\sqrt[3]{(3(1)+2)^{13}}}=\frac{280}{5^4\sqrt[3]{5}}$$

Then the Taylor Series follows:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3x+2}}=\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{5}}}{0!}(x-1)^0+\frac{\frac{-1}{5\sqrt[3]{5}}}{1!}(x-1)^1+\frac{\frac{4}{5^2\sqrt[3]{5}}}{2!}(x-1)^2+\frac{\frac{-28}{5^3\sqrt[3]{5}}}{3!}(x-1)^3+...$$

Where I have trouble is finding the nth term of the derivative. I know is alternating and that in the denominator there are powers of 5 multiplied by the cubic root of 5. But in the numerator, I don't see a pattern.

So by now I have, for the derivative I have $(-1)^{n}\frac{???}{5^n\sqrt[3]{5}}$

For the series: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{???}{5^nn!\sqrt[3]{5}}(x-1)^n$

Help with these, please. Then I could find the radius of convergence.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that$$f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt[3]{3(x-1)+5}}=\bigl(3(x-1)+5\bigr)^{-1/3}.$$Now, let $\varphi(x)=(x+5)^{-1/3}$. Then$$\varphi(x)=5^{-1/3}\left(1+\frac x5\right)^{-1/3}=5^{-1/3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-1/3}n\left(\frac x5\right)^n$$when $|x|<5$ and therefore\begin{align}f(x)&=\varphi\bigl(3(x-1)+5\bigr)\\&=5^{-1/3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-1/3}n\left(\frac35\right)^n(x-1)^n\end{align}when $|x-1|<\frac53$.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. So let me see if I'm getting it. You factor $3x+2$ as $3(x-1)+5$ because it is Taylor series around $x=1$ so we will need $(x-1)^n$? Then you factor out the 5 so we can have 1 plus something to have it in the form $(1+x)^k$? Last question, how do you come up with that $|x-1|<\frac{5}{3}$. I know that the radius of convergence of the binomial series around $x=0$ is $1$ but how do we use that information to get to the point that $|x-1|<\frac{5}{3}$?

Comment: The answer to your first two questions is affirmative. Then I use the fact that, if $\alpha\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$, then the radius of convergence of the binomial series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom\alpha nx^n$ is $1$. So, the radius of convergence of the series that I gave for $\varphi$ is $5$ (due to the presence of $\frac x5$). Now, due to that $3$ in $f(x)=\varphi\bigl(3(x-1)+5\bigr)$, the series that I gave for $f$ has radius of convergence $\frac53$, since it converges when $|3(x-1)|<5$, and diverges when $|3(x-1)|>5$.

Comment: Very understood! Muchas Gracias! <3